# AC_SUBST to specify additional source dir

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I have a configure that defines a variable as:

```
AC_ARG_WITH(mylib,
[  --with-mylib=PATH     Sets PATH for my additional sources (../mylib) ],
[
        MYLIB_PATH="${withval}"
        AC_MSG_RESULT(Using mylib source from ${withval})
],[
        MYLIB_PATH="../mylib"
])

dnl convert to absolute path
MYLIB_PATH=`readlink -f ${MYLIB_PATH}`
AC_SUBST(MYLIB_PATH)
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile src/Makefile)
```

My top-level `Makefile.am` is:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
SUBDIRS = src
```

Then in my `src/Makefile.am` I want to add sources from the specified mylib path:

```
...
bin_PROGRAMS = fooApp
fooApp_SOURCES = main.c \
            @MYLIB_PATH@/logger.c
fooApp_CFLAGS = -I@MYLIB_PATH@/lib
```

So the idea is that I keep a separate repository for those shared sources. During configure I can specify where I have them checkout. I.e.:

```
./configure --with-mylib=/tmp/mylib
```

Unfortunately when I run configure, the script appears to create a .deps (for the .Po files) under my src like it's stripping out the first slash of the path:

```
src/tmp/mylib/.deps/fooApp-logger.Po
```

Now, clearly make fails because it attempts to load the .Po file from the path: `/tmp/mylib/.deps/fooApp-logger.Po`

Any idea what am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to tell configure where to find my additional sources?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you're seeing the specific behavior you are seeing, but you're going about this very unconventionally.  If you have code that you want to use unchanged in multiple projects without copying it into each then the standard thing to do would be to build a library containing it, and then link the library to your other projects.  You can make it a static library if you like.  This will be a smoother path for you.

Comment: Hi John, Well, yes definitely a library is a way to go, but my projects target some embedded systems where it makes little sense to first group files into a library, then use the library in only one app. I know it's a fine line here and it can be open to interpretation (and different coding practice). My problem with AC_SUBST is weird. It seems that if I use a relative path for MYLIB_PATH, everything works as expected (the .deps dir is created in the right directory), but if MYLIB_PATH is absolute, it does not work.

Comment: Actually I have just tested that my situation works perfectly if I normalize MYLIB_PATH to be a relative path instead of absolute. I wonder if it's a bug with some of the autoconf macros... will investigate more and post a solution here.

Comment: If you're building the source in question for use in only one app for any given target platform, then your best course of action is probably to copy it into that app's own sources.  This has the advantage that you always know what version of the source went into the app.  What you describe seems to be designed for your own convenience in performing builds, which is a fine objective, but in this particular case it carries a large enough maintainability cost that I do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

All right for whoever facing a similar problem, I suspect is a problem with the automake that is doing something wrong when calculating the location of the path of the .Po files from an expanded path through AC_SUBST.

The workaround is to always use the relative path instead of absolute path when defining path that gets expanded through AC_SUBST.

In the example above, don't use ``` readlink`` to convert MYLIB_PATH to absolute, instead use ```realpath``` to find the relative path to the directory where the build is performed:

```
MYLIB_PATH=`realpath --relative-to src "${MYLIB_PATH}"`
```

I have created a full reproducer and filed a bug with GNU (bug#37499)